# Having Issue with Salesforce Contact Layout

Tags: salesforce

How can I add a new section to the contact layout in Salesforce ? After adding the New Section How can I add the value in that Particular field.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to drag-n-drop a field from the Fields layout section on the top.

[image: edit layout]